# Execute T-SQL stored procedure in update trigger with select from inserted as a parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Trying to pass the updated value to a stored procedure as a parameter inside an `update` trigger. What is the correct syntax to achieve this if possible?

I was looking for a way to use the select directly in the call to the stored procedure (using `execute`). There don't seem to be any other way inside an update trigger to retrieve the updated value than with

```
select from inserted
```

Most relevant solution would somehow move the select inside the called stored procedure if it returns a record set but I can't modify it and only have a scalar to pass. Hopefully I don't have to use local variable to pass the value, that seems possible but not elegant. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get the columns and column values got affected during Update of the Table

Comment: Yes, that's what the trigger does. I know which column I need so just get its new value and pass to the stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Column Names and Columns Values which got affected during `Update` and save those in a Audit table in the Database you may try the below trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_lOCATION_AUDIT] 
ON [dbo].[lOCATION] FOR UPDATE
AS
  DECLARE @bit INT ,
  @field INT ,
  @maxfield INT ,
  @char INT ,
  @fieldname VARCHAR(128) ,
  @TableName VARCHAR(128) ,
  @PKCols VARCHAR(1000) ,
  @sql VARCHAR(2000), 
  @UpdateDate VARCHAR(21) ,
  @UserName VARCHAR(128) ,
  @Type CHAR(1) ,
  @PKSelect VARCHAR(1000)


--You will need to change @TableName to match the table to be audited. 
-- Here we made GUESTS for your example.
SELECT @TableName = 'lOCATION'

-- date and user
SELECT         @UserName = SYSTEM_USER ,
       @UpdateDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
               + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 114)

-- Action
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
               SELECT @Type = 'U'
       ELSE
               SELECT @Type = 'I'
ELSE
       SELECT @Type = 'D'

-- get list of columns
SELECT * INTO #ins FROM inserted
SELECT * INTO #del FROM deleted

-- Get primary key columns for full outer join
SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') 
               + ' i.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + c.COLUMN_NAME
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,

              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

-- Get primary key select for insert
SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect+'+','') 
       + '''<' + COLUMN_NAME 
       + '=''+convert(varchar(100),
coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME +',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))+''>''' 
       FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
               INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
       WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
       AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

IF @PKCols IS NULL
BEGIN
       RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
       RETURN
END

SELECT         @field = 0, 
       @maxfield = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
WHILE @field < @maxfield
BEGIN
       SELECT @field = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
               AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @field
       SELECT @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1
       SELECT @bit = POWER(2,@bit - 1)
       SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1
       IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0
                                       OR @Type IN ('I','D')
       BEGIN
               SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME 
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                       WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
                       AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @field
               SELECT @sql = '
insert Audit (    Type, 
               TableName, 
               PK, 
               FieldName, 
               OldValue, 
               NewValue, 
               UpdateDate, 
               UserName)
select ''' + @Type + ''',''' 
       + @TableName + ''',' + @PKSelect
       + ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
       + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
       + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
       + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
       + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
       + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
       + @PKCols
       + ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
       + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.'
                                + @fieldname
                                + ' is not null)' 
       + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' 
                                + @fieldname
                                + ' is null)' 
               EXEC (@sql)
  END
END
```